# insert columns from three different unrelated table into 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tables `EMPLOYEE`, `PROJECT` and `DM_Manager` and there is no relation between them.
These 3 tables were created from parent table  named `Resource`.

Primary key for Project table and DM_Manager table  is generated by using Identity column.

I want to take PK columns from each table  and few columns from Resource table and create a new table.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am rookie in SQL Server.

Comment: "I want to take PK columns from each table and few columns from Resource table and create a new table." Well, if you want to create a new table, create one.You already did with you 3 tables. You are the one that choose you tables columns when you create it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT r.*, e.Id, p.Id, d.Id
INTO New_Table
FROM Resource r
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee e ON e.Id = r.EmployeeId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Project p ON p.Id = r.ProjectId
LEFT OUTER JOIN DM_Manager d ON d.Id = d.ManagerId
```

..that is, assuming that the tables Employee, Project and DM_Manager are unrelated to each other but all are related to the Resource table.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no relations at all this can be used:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (empID, projID, managerID, resourceID, resourcefield1)
SELECT employee.id, project.id, dm_manager.id, resource.id, resource.field1
FROM employee, project, dm_manager, resource;
```

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: got the below error after using this above query: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.